# BibTeX: found no \citation \bibdata \bibstyle

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I know there are some rather similar questions. I have read an tried most of them, but it doesn't work in my code.
simplified i use this code in my latex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtex.bib}


\begin{document}
test test\cite{Buch1}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I compile the code (using bibtex) in Texmaker I get folowing messages:

> ```
> Process started
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
> The top-level auxiliary file: TEst.aux
> I found no \citation commands---while reading file TEst.aux
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file TEst.aux
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file TEst.aux
> (There were 3 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)
> ```

I have already made sure, that the editor uses biber and not bibtex.
I also tried TexWorks but got same messages.
What else could be the problem?

Comment: You say "I have already made sure, that the editor uses biber and not bibtex." and you should be using biber, but your log clearly shows that you used bibtex.

Comment: Yaeh. I don't know why, I had biber in the setings. After closing TexMaker and opening it again it had bibtex back in the settings. But after changing that again, now it works.

Comment: For the link: The correct settings for Biber are at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: If it works now, I guess we can close this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Or do you want to close this question as unsubstantiated?